# How to change date format in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I change the date format query from mm/dd/YYYY to m/d/YY ??

For example 03/01/2019 to 3/1/19

```
select user_id, strftime('%m/%d/%Y', min(date)) as start_date, strftime('%m/%d/%Y', max(date)) as end_date, log as status,
       julianday(max(date)) - julianday(min(date)) + 1 as length
from (select users_log.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, log order by date) as seqnum
      from users_log
     ) users_log
group by user_id, log, date(date, '-' || seqnum || ' day')
order by min(date)
```

Comment: so u dont want in 03/01/19 Format? ie MM/DD/YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate each of the *day*, *month* and *year* with implicit conversions to integers so that leading `0`s are stripped off:

```
(date + 0) || '/' || (substr(date, 4, 2) + 0) || '/' || substr(date, -2)
```

change `date` to the name of your column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a8e73b8d1d766b348aabf6c0cedda6ce).

Comment: sorry, can you change it from 2019-01-03 to 1/3/19 ??

Comment: @alirezana Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=02888a127d2248fdfa261d619f5a7bca

Comment: Or this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5bf05cfc82c86244b01e945e234a616c if you want first the month